# I keep getting [object Object]. when I try to get data from the map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

when I put the normal function the map is listed normally, but as soon as I put it under the curly braces and the dollar, `I get the sign [object object]`.
I try to make a drill props my data. And i use star wars api (SWAPI)!

Thank you for answer!

This is how look like:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../Card/Card"; 
const CardList = ({ data, valueOfCard, propsdata }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-list">
        {data
          .filter((name) => `${name}.${propsdata}`)
          .slice(0, valueOfCard)
          .map((nameData) => (
            <Card people={`${nameData}.${propsdata}`} /> <-- {nameData.name} work normal
          ))}
      </div>  
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

Comment: Well `nameData` is an object. What is the shape of `nameData`? What's the shape of `propsdata`? What specifically are you trying to achieve?

Comment: most objects when coerced to String become `[object Object]` - that's how javascript works ... what is `nameData` and what output do you want from it

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing `[object Object]` as output text is that the javascript is providing the default string representation of a javasript object.

Since there is a "." just after the `[object Object]` text, I suspect that `nameData` is an object instead of something that can actually be interpreted as a string.

I am guessing that you're actually looking to use a specific `nameData` object property like the following:

```
<Card people={`${nameData.someObjectProperty}.${propsdata}`} />
```

To illustrate what's happening, you can run the following in a javascript debug console:

```
var a = {};
console.log(`${a}`);
```

Comment: .${propsdata}` it should give that property in the first place it`s work fine in filter line, but not in map..

Comment: @Mr.Ivančić, I don't believe it's working as you intend in the filter line. The filter callback takes a boolean expression, so if there is any object or text in either name or propsData, it will evaluate to true. Run the following js expressions in a console `!!\`\``, `!!\`0\``, `!!\`${{}}\``

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code but they make no sense to me:

- The callback you supplied to [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a string instead of boolean.
- The expression `${nameData}.${propsdata}` seems like a strange thing to display.

You were never clear about what you want your code to do. I can only guess. I assume:

1. You're trying to filter the items in `data` to get the one that has a property named by the value of `propsdata`; and
2. You're expecting `${nameData}.${propsdata}` to show the data of property of `nameData` named by the value of `propsdata`.

This assumption still doesn't explain why your `propsdata` apperantly clear empty (if `propsdata` has `"something"` in it, the output should be `"[object Object].something"` instead of `"[object Object]."`), but at least the code seem to make some sense.

If my assumptions were right, then you are seriously misunderstanding how to access javascript object property.

### The backtick: `

In javascript, the backtick character is used to declare [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). That is a kind of string that you may put variables in it. This lambda function:

```
(name) => `${name}.${propsdata}`
```

is identical to:

```
function (name) {
  return "" + name + "." + propsdata;
}
```

Javascript interpreters would try to turn both `name` and `propsdata` into string first, then concat them with ".". In your case, `name` is obviously an object and `propsdata` seems to be an empty string. Turning an object into string will give you `"[object Object]"`. This template literal will be evaluated into string `"[object Object]."`, which is always `true` for filtering.

### How to filter by property key?

To check if an object has a key, you can use [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). For example:

```js
data.hasOwnProperty("somekey");
```

Assuming you want only data that has a key dynamically specified by variable `propname`, you may do a filter like this:

```js
data
  .filter((name) => name.hasOwnProperty(propname))
```

### How to access an object property?

If you have an object `myobj` and you want to access its property named `"someprop"`, there are 2 types of syntax in javascript:

```js
myobj.someprop
```

and

```js
myobj["someprop"]
```

The second syntax style allow you to specify a property by the value of another variable. So you can do this:

```js
var myobj = {foo: "bar"};
var keyname = "foo";

console.log(foo[keyname]);
// result in console: bar
```

### How to fix the code?

If my assumptions are correct, you are probably looking for something like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Card from "../Card/Card"; 
const CardList = ({ data, valueOfCard, propsdata = "name" }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-list">
        {data
          .filter((nameData) => nameData.hasOwnProperty(propsdata))
          .slice(0, valueOfCard)
          .map((nameData) => (
            <Card people={nameData[propsdata]} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

Which still doesn't make much sense to me (why show arbitrary property in a card titled "character"?), but it makes more sense than the code you demonstrated.

If this is not what you wanted to do, my other guess was that you want to filter character by name (and the name is stored in `propsdata`). In that case:

```js
import React from "react";
import Card from "../Card/Card"; 
const CardList = ({ data, valueOfCard, propsdata }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="card-list">
        {data
          .filter((characterData) => (propsdata === "" || characterData.name === propsdata))
          .slice(0, valueOfCard)
          .map((nameData) => (
            <Card people={characterData.name} />
          ))}
      </div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

The expression `(propsdata === "" || characterData.name === propsdata)` would allow every character to pass if `propsdata` is an empty string.